# Buttons in a RelativeLayout disappear after changing LayoutParams

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout, android-view, android-button

I have five buttons in a Relative layout, if I try to change their height dynamically, some buttons disappear.

[How buttons are looking before clicking](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ijbab.jpg)

[Buttons after clicking](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cUtcS.jpg)

```
val w = TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 45f, resources.displayMetrics)
    btn_ran.setOnClickListener {
        btn_1.layoutParams = RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(w.toInt(), 700)
        btn_3.layoutParams = RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(w.toInt(), 700)
        btn_4.layoutParams = RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(w.toInt(), 700)
        btn_2.layoutParams = RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(w.toInt(), 700)
        btn_5.layoutParams = RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(w.toInt(), 700)

    }
```

All I want to do is to change all of the button's height randomly on the click of a button.

Comment: They might be getting out of screen view. Try putting this inside a scroll view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If You only want to change `height` to random value You can do it in this way:

```
button1.setOnClickListener {
    val h = (100..500).random() //random integer between 100 and 500
    button1.layoutParams.height = h
    button2.layoutParams.height = h
    button1.requestLayout() //refresh layout
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that you are losing the *relative positioning* attributes when you create new `LayoutParams` objects. Remember that attributes like `layout_toEndOf` are part of the layout params.

Try this instead:

```
val w = TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 45f, resources.displayMetrics)
btn_ran.setOnClickListener {
    btn_1.updateLayoutParams { this.width = w }
    btn_3.updateLayoutParams { this.width = w }
    btn_4.updateLayoutParams { this.width = w }
    btn_2.updateLayoutParams { this.width = w }
    btn_5.updateLayoutParams { this.width = w }
}
```

This makes use of [the `updateLayoutParams` extension function](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/core/view/package-summary#updatelayoutparams) that is part of the Core KTX library. It will keep everything about the `LayoutParams` the same, but also allow you to modify the width.

If you can't use Core KTX, then you can be a little more verbose. Replace each of those calls with something like this:

```
val params1 = btn_1.layoutParams
params1.width = w
btn_1.layoutParams = params1
```